# NgRx can't select from store

Tags: angular, rxjs, store, ngrx

I am doing a very simple implementation of NgRx, right now just doing the get for one component. The data comes through in the payload according to the Redux Devtool, but I cant seem to access it through the async pipe.

Devtool:

[image: redux dev tool state]
[image: redux dev tools image payload]

---UPDATE----

the problem is when i access the slice in my ts file, i get the error

> Argument of type '"network"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '"start"'.

ts file

```
constructor(private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>) {}
getDns() {
        // reach out to ngrx store
        this.dnsServers$ = this.store.select('network').map(network => network.dns)
        console.log(this.dnsServers$)
        // get current dns IPs'
        this.networkService.getDns()
            .subscribe(
                (dnsList: Dns) => {
                    console.log(dnsList.dns);
                    this.store.dispatch(
                        new LoadIpSuccessAction(dnsList.dns)
                    )
                }
            )
    }
```

my feature module

`StoreModule.forFeature('network', { dns: dnsReducer })`

my root reducer (I do not have any modules not loaded lazy, so my root reducer is empty... Not sure how to make it work otherwise)

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export interface State {
    start: string;
}

const initialState: State = {
    start: ''
}

export function startReducer(state = initialState, action: Action) {
    return state;
}
```

and my updated feature reducer to access the dns array

```
import * as NetworkActions from './network.actions';
import * as fromApp from '../../store/app.reducers';

export interface NetworkState extends fromApp.AppState {
    dns: DnsState;
}

export interface DnsState {
    dns: string[];
}

const initialState: DnsState = {
    dns: []
}

export function dnsReducer(state = initialState, action: NetworkActions.DnsActions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case NetworkActions.LOAD_IP_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                dns: [...action.payload]
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: try setting the definition of dnsServer = this.store.select('dns') outside of getDns(). Also set type to Obseravble for dnsServer if you using types.

Comment: getDns() is being called in ngOninit() so I doesnt matter if it is outside. and I will eventually get to typing the observable, but that isnt solving the problem

Comment: I think I know. the return payload object might be a different value than what subscribe gets then sets right after. Might be just empty initially and async gets nothing back but later updates after the dispatch. However by expecting a DNS from undefined, your causing it to error out. Hence why it fails without safety operator but works with safety. The values later update to working ones.

if you set the default state to be an object with DNS and some fake values, it will work....try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor, `store` refers to the entire app state, not just `network`. It should be

```
constructor(..., private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>) {}
```

You'll need to access it using

```
this.dnsServers$ = this.store.select('network').map(network => network.dns);
```

In addition, `action.payload` is `{dns: ["6.7.7.7", "5.5.5.5"]}`. When you assign it in your reducer, you are doing `dns: [action.payload]`, so you're ending up with the `NetworkState` being:

```
{
    dns: [
        { dns: ["6.7.7.7", "5.5.5.5"] }
        ]
}
```

If you want to reduce the logic in your constructors every time you want a slice of the state, you can use selectors:

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from "@ngrx/store";

export const selectNetwork = createFeatureSelector<fromNetwork.NetworkState>('network');
export const selectNetworkDns = createSelector(selectNetwork, (state) => state.dns);
```

To use it in your constructor:

```
constructor(private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>) {
    this.dnsServers$ = this.store.select(selectNetworkDns);
}
```

Comment: I figured it out. in my module I had `StoreModule.forFeature('network', dnsReducer)` instead of `StoreModule.forFeature('dns', dnsReducer)` and I yes I was passing the object not the list, so that helped as well. I have multiple reducers under the state 'network' so i'm gonna have to figure out how to structure that...

Comment: You can pass an object in: `.forFeature('network', { dns: dnsReducer, otherThing: otherThingReducer})`. Also take a look at [selectors](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md). It will remove any need to call `.map()` after `.select()` just to get a slice of the state.

Comment: oh man, you are the best, that's exactly what I was looking for! one thing though, how do you access dns from the network slice? thanks! if you want to update your answer to include that as well, I'll mark it down

Comment: This is a lazy loaded feature, so I have to access it from the network state

Comment: thanks for the update! the only problem is it's lazy loaded, So I cant access it through the main appstate, it extends the app state.

Comment: If `network` is lazy loaded, it won't exist in the app state until that module is loaded. The feature selectors are just plain old functions, they won't run until you call them. As long as you only call them in components in the lazy loaded module, there won't be any issue.

Comment: You can also use an object in the top level store instead of a reducer: `StoreModule.forRoot({})`. Also, I made a mistake on the typings. I misread your NetworkState interface. If you switch back to `Store<fromNetwork.NetworkState>` I think that should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156698/discussion-between-fussinhussin-and-cdbajorin).